# Failed Constraint - how to correctly insert something in a sqlite3 table?

Tags: sqlite

We were asked to create a database, then a table, then fill it with the givens. 
Here's what I have come up with so far:

```
sqlite3 me5.db;

create table petID(pet_id int(3) PRIMARY KEY, pet_name varchar(10), pet_type varchar(10), pet_age int(3));

INSERT INTO petID(pet_id, pet_name, pet_type, pet_age) VALUES(246, 'ROVER', 'DOG', 12);
INSERT INTO petID(pet_id, pet_name, pet_type, pet_age) VALUES(298, 'SPOT', 'DOG', 2);
INSERT INTO petID(pet_id, pet_name, pet_type, pet_age) VALUES(341, 'MORRIS', 'CAT', 4);
INSERT INTO petID(pet_id, pet_name, pet_type, pet_age) VALUES(519, 'TWEEDY', 'BIRD', 2);

create table petowner(pet_id int(3), owner varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY(pet_id) REFERENCES petID(pet_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO petowner(pet_id, owner) VALUES(246, 'SAM COOK');
INSERT INTO petowner(pet_id, owner) VALUES(298, 'TERRY KIM');
```

However, when I insert these two below:

```
INSERT INTO petowner(pet_id, owner) VALUES(341, 'SAM COOK');
INSERT INTO petowner(pet_id, owner) VALUES(519, 'TERRY KIM');
```

I get a 'constraint failed' error. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The constraint that you violated is the primary key of `petowner`; it prevents `'SAM COOK'` appearing twice.

If a pet can have multiple owners, then the primary key of the `petowner` table must contain both columns:

```
CREATE TABLE petowner(
    pet_id int(3),
    owner varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(pet_id, owner),
    FOREIGN KEY(pet_id) REFERENCES petID(pet_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```